# Remote WOL over CISCO/FW not Forwarding

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, cisco, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to accomplish a Wake-on-LAN by triggering the two servers' public IP addresses.

Internally, the WOL works like a charm (by either the internal or external IP), externally however, it does not wake when the IP addresses are triggered.

The firewall, DC and WS all have their own IP addresses, controlled and forwarded by the CISCO. I've requested the ISP to open broadcasting on port 7 and 9 UDP to the internal network, which they have done. Still, it doesn't work.

Could someone assist in getting a solution to wake these on LAN? Our country's electrical situation isn't of the best, and with roving black-outs regularly occurring (and our limited budget for long-duration backup power), I need to get such a feature working.

TeamViewer WOL is a bust - doesn't work at all.

I currently have a network set up in the following order:

[image]

WWW -> CISCO 800series unit -> Cyberoam firewall -> DC

Comment: Is the Cyberoam firewall blocking UDP7,9? Do you see the incoming UDP traffic in the Cyberoam logs?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled directed-broadcast on the incoming interface?

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-3750-series-switches/91672-catl3-wol-vlans.html#WOL